# "T" key came out of keyboard - need advice

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

My "T" key came out of it's spot on my late 13 inch 2013 retina macbook pro., the key and the mechanism attached to it. No apple stores in the country so I'm on my own. I tried putting it back in it's place but it keeps coming out.

Now the question is: could there be a possibility where the clips underneath (not the plastic mechanism) could've been bent/damaged and that's why it's not being seated properly? Has anyone heard of such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Ronald I'm Kali :) have you tries turning your computer completely off and pressing it as hard as you can well, not as hard as you can but put force on it...and you should hear a "pop" when it pops back into place. Please let me  know if this helps you :)